# countdown timer using php, can't make it work

Tags: php, timer, countdowntimer

i am making a php countdown timer that display only minutes and seconds.

here is my code:

```
$time = "10:00";
$time_min = substr($time, 0,2);
echo $time_sec = substr($time, 3) . "<br>";
$current = date("i:s");
$target = date("i:s" , mktime(0,$time_min,0,0,0,0));
echo $current-$target . "<br>";
echo $target;
```

the output should be the remaining time from the time the user opens the page.

Comment: I assume you are not using ajax to update the remaining time every n seconds?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob i am using this in tandem of a jquery timer. this php timer will go directly to the database as an audit trail.

Comment: @RakeshSharma the remaining time from the 10 minute duration from the time the page is opened.

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: @FerozAkbar i cant make it work, the code logic is wrong

Comment: How does your code not work? Can you please be more specific? Does your php error log show any errors?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob the timer is increasing instead of it decreasing even if i put on the current time minus the target time

Comment: $time = "10:00";
 $current = date("i:s");
 $remain = $current-$target . "<br>";
echo date('i:s', time($remain));

Comment: @RakeshSharma, its working but its increasing. i need the timer to decrease until end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the details of your jQuery I am taking a shot at this.

I prefer working in seconds, so to get the $timeRemaining (you must know the initial time to do this) at any given instant in the 10 minute window, I would do this:

```
$targetTime = time() + 600; //you have to save this either in database or as variable somewhere
```

Then on subsequent opening of relevant php file the following code could be used if targetTime is saved in database

```
$sqlTime = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT targetTime FROM timeTable WHERE id = '$myID'"));
$currentTime = time();
$timeRemaining = (($sqlTime['targetTime'] - $currentTime) / 60) . ":" . (($sqlTime['targetTime'] - $currentTime) % 60);
```

Comment: i tried using the $targetTime instead of the sql value. the timer isn't moving when i tried refreshing the page.

Comment: Are you storing the initial $targetTime as an int in a table, and giving it a unique id?